# Wrapping C++ Library in Python, handling custom types

Tags: c++, python, wrapper, word-wrap

i'm currently writing a NLP application in python which requires a fast POS tagging implementation. the tagger has a c++ wrapper interface:

```
#include "POSTagger.h"

extern "C" POSTagger* initTagger(const char* fileName, bool Normalize, 
                                 double BeamThreshold, bool SentStartHeuristic,
                                 int MaxBeamSize)
{
    FILE *file = open_file(fileName, "rb");
    POSTagger* tagger = new POSTagger(file, Normalize, BeamThreshold, 
                                      SentStartHeuristic, MaxBeamSize);
    fclose(file);
    return tagger;
}


extern "C" void getTags(POSTagger* tagger, char** words, int sentLen, 
                        char** tags)
{
    Sentence sent(words, sentLen);
    tagger->annotate(sent);

    for( size_t i=0; i<sent.token.size(); i++ )
        tags[i] = strdup(tagger->tagmap.name(sent.token[i].tag));
}


extern "C" void destroyTagger(POSTagger* tagger) {
    delete tagger;
}
```

i've never written a wrapper for c++ in python yet. so there are a couple of questions:

1. Can i store a custom C++ class instance in python?
   i've never seen that before. all examples that i did go through returned only basic data types.
   (this pos tagger has to be initialized with a language set, which requires some time to load it into the memory. therefore it is essential to only init and store it rather than rewriting the wrapper to create one for every tagging procedure and just return a tagged string)
2. If 1 is possible: what is the easiest way?

Comment: C doesn't have classes. Do you mean C++?

Comment: @Daenyth sorry, just edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use *Cython* for this purpose. Writing C/C++ extension-types is straight forward.

Unfortunately, I can't garuantee this code to be fully correct as I can't test it without the header you use.
    # coding:   utf-8
    # file:     postagger.pyx

```
cimport libc.stdlib     as stdlib

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    char* PyString_AsString(object)

cdef extern from "yourPOSTagger.c":

    # note the syntax, to Cython the POSTagger class will be available
    # as cPOSTagger using this construct
    cppclass cPOSTagger "POSTagger":
        # we only need the POSTagger type to be available to cython
        # but no attributes, so we leave to ``pass``
        pass

    cPOSTagger* initTagger(char*, bint, double, bint, int)
    void        getTags(cPOSTagger*, char**, int, char**)
    void        destroyTagger(cPOSTagger*)

cdef class POSTagger:
    """ Wraps the POSTagger.h ``POSTagger`` class. """

    cdef cPOSTagger*    tagger

    def __init__(self, char* fileName, bint Normalize, double BeamTreshold,
                       bint SentStartHeuristic, int MaxBeamSize):
        self.tagger = initTagger( fileName, Normalize, BeamTreshold,
                                  SentStartHeuristic, MaxBeamSize )
        if self.tagger == NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __del__(self):
        destroyTagger(self.tagger)

    def getTags(self, tuple words, int sentLen):
        if not words:
            raise ValueError("'words' can not be None.")

        cdef char** _words = <char**> stdlib.malloc(sizeof(char*) * len(words))
        cdef int    i      = 0
        for item in words:
            if not isinstance(item, basestring):
                stdlib.free(_words)
                raise TypeError( "Element in tuple 'words' must be of type "
                                 "``basestring``." )
            _words[i] = PyString_AsString(item)
            i += 1

        cdef int nTags   = len(words)   # Really? Dunno..
        cdef char** tags = <char**> stdlib.malloc(sizeof(char*) * len(words))

        getTags(self.tagger, _words, sentLen, tags)

        cdef list reval = []
        cdef str  temp
        for 0 <= i < nTags:
            temp = tags[i]
            reval.append(temp)
            stdlib.free(tags[i])

        stdlib.free(tags)

        return reval
```

You'd need this code to compile with the `--cplus` flag with *Cython*.

**EDIT**: Corrected code, Cython does no more give errors.

Comment: first of all thank you @niklas for taking some time. i really appreciate it! cython gives me multiple compiling errors, it seams mainly because cython can't compile the double pointer to char. the source code can be obtained from http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/corplex/RFTagger/

Comment: edited two typos in line 44 & 52 `_words`. getting error for line 28: bool is not type identifier.

Comment: @sebastianmarkow I've edited the code, Cython does not give me any errors now. I messed up some names as you already denoted, forgot to change the `bool` to `bint` and I've but the underscore for the c-datatype variable at the end at two places. Anyway, but dependencies does the library need? I get many errors when compiling with g++.

Comment: there are no external dependencies. normally i would compile it like stated in the `README`.

Comment: Can you compile successfully? I get errors like `RFTagger\src/Lexicon.h:77: error: 'class SymbolTable' has no member named 'end'
RFTagger\src/Lexicon.h:79: error: 'it' was not declared in this scope`. Even following the steps the README describes, using `make`, gives me errors. I'm on windows so I'm using `mingw32-make`.. I'm not an expert at C/C++ at all, so.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to create an opaque type that can be pushed around in Python but that the client doesn't really have to care about.

Comment: how would one do that? any examples? or docs where you can point me?

Comment: The normal extemb docs have an example for creating a type; just add an attribute to hold the pointer.